# Event Handling in Android (setOnClickListener)

Tags: android, events

I'm new to Java and Android Development in General. I found a sample which uses the following statement.

```
sButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in the onCreate() method of the Activity which implements View.OnClickListener where sButton is a Button variable. As far as I understand this register the on click event handler
Later in the sample

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button_s)
    {
    //some work
    }
```

this happens.
My question is if it uses the 'this' keyword from inside the activity shouldn't it pass an object of class Activity? If that happens then the Button ID would never match.

I know there are other methods to implement the Button click.

I have a bit of experience with C# and Windows Phone. The procedure there was that the methods were called for the respective buttons without any need for registering them.

Also what is the difference between event handlers and listeners?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your Activity implements ClickListener , it will be passed to the `setOnClickListener()` method , the view passed to the `onClick(View v)` is the view that is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnClickListener` (in this case the Activity instance) is used to declare the behaviour of your application when it consumes click event. However, your application's Main (UI) Thread registers all (UI) events and it will dispatch the appropriate `View` object as a parameter to your `onClick(View v)` function.

The snippet you provided - `sButton.setOnClickListener(this)` simply instructs your application to use the implemented `OnClickListener` inside your Activity implementation to respond to user clicks. It doesn't forward the `this` instance as the parameter to the `onClick()` function, Android OS does that.

In conclusion: The `View v` parameter in your `onClick(View v)` function will correspond to the `View` that the user clicked, regardless of the `OnClickListener` that has been attached to that `View`

EDIT: [This](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java#View.performClick%28%29) is (perhaps outdated but) Android's source-code for the `performClick()` method of the `View` class. As you can see, inside that method it calls the `mOnClickListener.onClick(this)` if there's a listener attached, and that's how the view that has been clicked is forwarded to the `onClick()` method of the appropriate `onClickListener` object.

Comment: Could you paste any links which would provide more information on the way this actually works? As I understand it from your answer the OS sends the Required view which is activated and hides how this actually happens in my code. Is this true?

Comment: Updated answer with link to the Android's source-code, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1):

One is below

```
Button btn_stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            }
        });
```

Second is through XML **android:onClick="doClick"**

below is code for activity

```
public void doClick(View v)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
sButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

`this` is indeed an instance of `Activity`. But it is declared as

```
MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

The important part is that it implements the interface that `setOnClickListener` takes as argument. This is why it works, `this` is treated as an `OnClickListener`, regardless of being an `Activity` or not.

As for the difference between event handlers and listeners, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725241/whats-the-difference-between-event-listeners-handlers-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had come across it before posting the question, however it still doesn't really give concrete differences between them.